# Почему не работает добавление стиля для Dom элемента по setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование

подскажите, пожалуйста, почему не работает setTimeout?

Нужно, чтобы через 2 секунды для Dom элемента добавлялось css свойство.

```js
let testAnim = document.querySelector('.load2');
let testTime = setTimeout(() => {
    testAnim.style.display = 'flex';
}, 2000);
```

```css
.load2 {
  display: none !important;
}

.is-typing {
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 50px;
    justify-content: space-around;
    display: flex;
}

.jump1,
.jump2,
.jump3,
.jump4,
.jump5 {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background-color: gray;
}

.jump1 {
    animation: typing 1.5s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: 01.1s;
}

.jump2 {
    animation: typing 1.5s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: 01.2s;
}

.jump3 {
    animation: typing 1.5s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: 01.3s;
}

.jump4 {
    animation: typing 1.5s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: 01.4s;
}

.jump5 {
    animation: typing 1.5s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: 1.5s;
}

@keyframes typing {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(0px);
    }

    25% {
        transform: translateY(0px);
    }

    35% {
        transform: translateY(15px);
    }

    45% {
        transform: translateY(0px);
    }

    60% {
        transform: translateY(-15px);
    }

    75% {
        background-color: white;
        transform: translateY(0px);
    }

    100% {
        transform: translateY(0px);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <div class="is-typing load2">
            <div class="jump1"></div>
            <div class="jump2"></div>
            <div class="jump3"></div>
            <div class="jump4"></div>
            <div class="jump5"></div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Уберите `!important` и поменяйте местами

```
.is-typing {
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 50px;
    justify-content: space-around;
    display: flex;
}

.load2 {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Просто уберите класс с этим важным наном.

```js
let testAnim = document.querySelector('.load2');
let testTime = setTimeout(() => {
    testAnim.classList.remove('load2');
}, 2000);
```

```css
.load2 {
  display: none !important;
}

.is-typing {
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 50px;
    justify-content: space-around;
    display: flex;
}

.jump1,
.jump2,
.jump3,
.jump4,
.jump5 {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background-color: gray;
}

.jump1 {
    animation: typing 1.5s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: 01.1s;
}

.jump2 {
    animation: typing 1.5s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: 01.2s;
}

.jump3 {
    animation: typing 1.5s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: 01.3s;
}

.jump4 {
    animation: typing 1.5s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: 01.4s;
}

.jump5 {
    animation: typing 1.5s linear infinite;
    animation-delay: 1.5s;
}

@keyframes typing {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(0px);
    }

    25% {
        transform: translateY(0px);
    }

    35% {
        transform: translateY(15px);
    }

    45% {
        transform: translateY(0px);
    }

    60% {
        transform: translateY(-15px);
    }

    75% {
        background-color: white;
        transform: translateY(0px);
    }

    100% {
        transform: translateY(0px);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <div class="is-typing load2">
            <div class="jump1"></div>
            <div class="jump2"></div>
            <div class="jump3"></div>
            <div class="jump4"></div>
            <div class="jump5"></div>
        </div>
</div>
```